# understanding heroku log using Angular

Tags: angular, heroku

I have an Angular app running fine on localhost but when i upload to Heroku i am recieving an error.

```
2018-09-13T09:33:53.944829+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2018-09-13T09:33:53.944831+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T09:33:53.954809+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2018-09-13T09:33:53.967562+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-09-13T09:33:53.967902+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-09-13T09:33:53.968250+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-09-13T09:33:53.968589+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-09-13T09:33:53.970548+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! taccountproui@0.0.0 
start: `ng serve`
2018-09-13T09:33:53.970808+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-09-13T09:33:53.971162+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-09-13T09:33:53.971426+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
taccountproui@0.0.0 start script.
2018-09-13T09:33:53.971682+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-09-13T09:33:54.000551+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2018-09-13T09:33:53.994215+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T09:33:54.000772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-13T09_33_53_973Z-debug.log
2018-09-13T09:33:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-09-13T09:34:03.177179+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T09:34:03.177204+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2018-09-13T09:34:03.177202+00:00 app[web.1]: > taccountproui@0.0.0 start 
/app
2018-09-13T09:34:03.177206+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T09:34:03.193831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-09-13T09:34:03.194392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-09-13T09:34:03.194631+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-09-13T09:34:03.188316+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2018-09-13T09:34:03.196406+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! taccountproui@0.0.0 
start: `ng serve`
2018-09-13T09:34:03.194141+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-09-13T09:34:03.208289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2018-09-13T09:34:03.196593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-09-13T09:34:03.197062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
taccountproui@0.0.0 start script.
2018-09-13T09:34:03.196865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-09-13T09:34:03.197294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-09-13T09:34:03.208066+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T09:34:03.208437+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-13T09_34_03_199Z-debug.log
```

I Can not find the error. Where is the  /app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-13T09_34_03_199Z-debug.log file?

here are some more logs:

```
    2018-09-12T18:30:39.210236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
    desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taccountproui.herokuapp.com 
    request_id=6b006b87-9290-4b12-bae8-73e8e620ecbf fwd="86.40.243.210" 
    dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2018-09-12T18:30:41.427199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taccountproui.herokuapp.com request_id=2f4b89de-5746-4e8c-b2b3-fff0a0ecdfda fwd="86.40.243.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

2018-09-12T18:30:53.477386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taccountproui.herokuapp.com request_id=1dd887be-b7fa-4c0b-b657-ea8d773082f4 fwd="86.40.243.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-12T18:30:54.380182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taccountproui.herokuapp.com request_id=bb69a40b-52b4-4ff8-b4f7-9391c3a8ed67 fwd="86.40.243.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Can you try running this first? `npm link @angular/cli` This is to let npm know what ng means

Comment: when i run i get:
C:\Users\laptop\Documents\t account pro angular\taccountproui\node_modules\@angular\cli -> C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli

Comment: You don't get an error message though, right? Now try buildilng

Comment: no error. by build what do you mean? upload to Heroku again or run locally

Comment: how do i see whats causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

ng serve does not work on heroku.
The recommended way to get it running is by adding a file (Procfile) in your project folder.
Procfile:

```
web: node dist/server
```

Heroku will use that proccess to start your application instead of the start script in your package.json.

You could also create a new script-command to your package.json. For example:

```
"serveonheroku": "node dist/server",
```

and the Procfile:

```
web: npm run serveonheroku
```